# „persuading” tabulate function to count NAs in a data frame in [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

I’d like to ask you a question again. It is basically about data frames, NAs and tabulate function in [R].

I have this data frame. I already used this in a previous question of mine. It intentionally looks this simple, my real ’df’ dataframe is much bigger actually and again, I am not willing to annoy anyone with huge databases… So, my database:

```
id <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
a <-c(3,1,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,3,3,3,2,1,1,3)
b <-c(3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,2)
c <-c(1,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,2)
d <-c(3,3,3,1,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2)
e <-c(2,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3,2,1,4)
df <-data.frame(id,a,b,c,d,e)
df
```

I have managed to calculate the distributions of the numbers occurring in columns ’b’ to ’e’ but considering the fact at the very same time that these distributions should be ’groupped by’ the id numbers in column ’id’. It works fine, check it ->

```
matrix(matrix(unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))], 
       function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,
                          nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,2])))) [[1]])), 
              ncol=3,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

matrix(matrix(unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,3])))) [[2]])),ncol=3,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

matrix(matrix(unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,4])))) [[3]])),ncol=3,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

matrix(matrix(unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,5])))) [[4]])),ncol=3,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

matrix(matrix(unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,6])))) [[5]])),ncol=4,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
```

Now my problem is: what if my data frame contains NA values here and there and what if I want my in-built tabulate function to collect these NAs as well? So what if I want it to count how many occurrences I have from these NAs?

Here’s my modified data frame with the NAs:

```
id <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
a <-c(NA,1,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,3,2,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,3,3,3,2,1,1,3)
b <-c(3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,2)
c <-c(1,3,2,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,3,NA,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,2)
d <-c(3,3,3,1,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,2)
e <-c(2,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3,NA,1,4)
df <-data.frame(id,a,b,c,d,e)
df
```

At first I tried something like this:

```
unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,2],exclude=NULL)))) [[1]])
```

You see, the only thing I did was that I tried to apply this `exclude=NULL` thing.

At least my code realizes the fact that I have 4 different levels in column `a` `(1,2,3,NA)` and not only three `(1,2,3)`. Check it here:

```
nlevels(factor(df[,2], exclude=NULL))
```

But you see in the result that somehow it could not calculate the NAs. It says

```
3  0  6  0  4  3  3  0  4  1  5  0
```

Instead of the correct:

```
3  0  6  1  4  3  3  0  4  1  5  0
```

Or in case of:

```
unlist(lapply(df[,(-(1))],function(x) tapply(x,df$id,tabulate,nbins=nlevels(factor(df[,4],exclude=NULL)))) [[3]])
```

It says

```
2  4  4  0  2  3  4  0  1  5  4  0
```

Instead of the correct

```
2  4  4  0  2  3  4  1  1  5  4  0
```

etc.

Does someone have any ideas how to "persuade" the function tabulate to count NAs? Is it possible at all?

Thanks very much and have a pleasant weekend,

Laszlo

Comment: -1 this was also posted in r-help

Comment: @G. Grothendieck --- Gabor, that is an inappropriate use of the voting system IMHO. The voting mechanism aims to identify useful or clear Q versus not useful or unclear Qs. SO is a separate entity to R-Help why should it matter if the Q is posted there and here? It's not as if @Laszlo spammed several SE sites with his Q.

Comment: Also, whoever voted to close as "not a real Q", how do you get that opinion? The Q is reasonably clear once you get passed the over-explicit code. @Laszlo wants wants to count `NA` as well as the other levels of a factor.

Comment: @GS, Questions posted in multiple venues split the answers and discussions.  They ought to be closed to discourage that unless time has gone by without an answer.

Comment: @Gabor - but that is **not** what the voting mechansim is for here. And why is R-help the "main" venue for posting Q's - which is what you appear to be saying. It could be argued that this Q was posted here *before* R-Help.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck and the person who voted to close: Please see this SO Meta posting which deals with the sort of cross-posting you find so intolerable: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/22657/155539  The consensus there was that there was **nothing** wrong with what @Laszlo has done. You are entitled to your opinion - an admonishing comment could have voiced it - but downvoting *and* voting to close (under a spurious pretence - not a real Q) aren't appropriate uses of these community management tools.

Comment: Hello everyone! I am terribly sorry, I really did not intend to hurt or insult anybody. I was just really afraid that maybe I would not get an answer because of my long e-mail. I just hoped that maybe I can increase the possibility that someone might find my question interesting and thus gives me a hint, that is all. Hereby I would like to apologise. You know I have just discovered this website and found it quite useful, I have already learned numerous things which I have to thank you for that. And also thank you for your answers, Gavin and „gsk3”, they were really beneficial.

Comment: One more thing: like Gavin said, I can assure every one of you I did not 'spam' any other sites with my e-mail. I guess my double-posting here and at the R-help page was some kind of an etiquette-matter which I was not aware of. I accept that, it was my fault. I am terribly sorry again for causing you this inconvenience. I can also assure you that if I had gotten my answer at R help first I would surely have pasted the answer’s link here so that others could make a use of my experience. Thank you for your opinions/answers again! Best regards, Laszlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your repeated calls to:

```
tabs <-lapply(df[,2:6], function(x, id){ t(table(x, id)) }, df$id)
```

which gives almost the same as your repeated matrix calls, e.g. for your first (non-NA) one:

```
> tabs[[1]]
   x
id  1 2 3
  1 3 0 7
  2 4 3 3
  3 4 1 5
```

So can we now modify this to deal with `NA`? Yes, using the `useNA` argument of the `table()` function. Using your `df` with `NA`, we have:

```
tabs <-lapply(df[,2:6], 
              function(x, id){ t(table(x, id, useNA = "ifany")) }, df$id)

> tabs[[1]]
   x
id  1 2 3 <NA>
  1 3 0 6    1
  2 4 3 3    0
  3 4 1 5    0
```

Because we ask for `NA` in the table **only** if an `NA` exists, not all the tables in `tabs` have the same number of columns. If that is important, we can change `useNA = "ifany"` to be `useNA = "always"` and all the result tables will have the same number of columns, however it adds another id row:

```
> tabs[[1]]
      x
id     1 2 3 <NA>
  1    3 0 6    1
  2    4 3 3    0
  3    4 1 5    0
  <NA> 0 0 0    0
```

One final addition gets what we want - we use `addNA()` to add an `NA` level to each `id`'s set of numbers, even if there are no `NA`s recorded:

```
tabs <-lapply(df[,2:6], 
              function(x, id){ t(table(addNA(x), id, useNA = "ifany")) }, df$id)
```

Which gives:

```
> tabs
$a

id  1 2 3 <NA>
  1 3 0 6    1
  2 4 3 3    0
  3 4 1 5    0

$b

id  1 2 3 <NA>
  1 8 1 1    0
  2 6 3 1    0
  3 2 4 4    0

$c

id  1 2 3 <NA>
  1 2 4 4    0
  2 2 3 4    1
  3 1 5 4    0

$d

id  1 2 3 <NA>
  1 2 3 5    0
  2 2 6 2    0
  3 5 3 2    0

$e

id  1 2 3 4 <NA>
  1 4 3 3 0    0
  2 4 2 4 0    0
  3 1 3 4 1    1
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they downvoted the answer?

Comment: I think I know who and why - and if my suspicions are correct, the downvote is IMHO another misuse (abuse) of the voting system.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `is.na`?  If you want to count up the number of entries that are NA or non-zero, you could `sum(is.na(my.var)|my.var>0)`.